# How can I have validation errors printed on failure

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, bean-validation

given the following dto and controller

```
public class PasswordCredentials implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty( access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY )
    private String user;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty( access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY )
    private CharSequence pass;


    public void setPass( final CharSequence pass ) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public void setUser( final String user ) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication toAuthentication() {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( user, pass );
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping( path = "authentication" )
class AuthenticationController {
    private final AuthenticationManager am;

    AuthenticationController( final AuthenticationManager am ) {
        this.am = am;
    }

    @RequestMapping( path = "password", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        "!" + MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE
    } )
    ResponseEntity<?> login( @Valid @RequestBody final PasswordCredentials credentials ) {
        Authentication authenticate = am.authenticate( credentials.toAuthentication() );
        if ( authenticate.isAuthenticated() ) {
            return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT ).build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN ).build();
    }

}
```

if for example `pass` is null there will be a validation error, and a 400 will happen without ever calling my controller, which is fine. That 400 however has no content, **is there any way to have the controllers `BindResults` output as content so that the consumer of the API knows what caused the problem?** Ideally I would not do this in the controller method, so that it would happen on all controllers?

I was able to get this behavior with spring data rest as follows, but I'd like it for all API controllers.

```
class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }


    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(
            final ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener ) {
        Validator validator = validator();
        //bean validation always before save and create
        validatingListener.addValidator( "beforeCreate", validator );
        validatingListener.addValidator( "beforeSave", validator );
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration( final RepositoryRestConfiguration config ) {
        config.setBasePath( "/v0" );
        config.setReturnBodyOnCreate( false );
        config.setReturnBodyOnUpdate( false );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring have `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotation to handle errors in controllers.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Error processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
         BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        .....
        return new Error();
    }

    // Other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i want to improve the answer of Anton Novopashin: just return the error in response entity.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionTranslator {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // Other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure who or why downvoted the existing answers but they are both right - the best way to handle validation errors would be to declare a `@ControllerAdvice` and then handle the exceptions there. Here's a snippet of my global error handler, taken from an existing project:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class RestfulErrorHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ErrorResponse methodValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        final ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
        for (ObjectError error : e.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
            if (error instanceof FieldError) {
                response.addFieldError((FieldError) error);
            } else {
                response.addGeneralError(error.getDefaultMessage());
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ErrorResponse constraintViolationError(ConstraintViolationException e) {
        final ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> v : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            response.addFieldError(v.getPropertyPath(), v.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

You should also process `ConstraintViolationException`s since they too may be thrown. Here's [a link to my `ErrorResponse` class](https://gist.github.com/FingolfinTEK/0951f548a216284cb27c3bdeb95d252a), I'm including it as a Gist so as not to obscure the main point.

You should also probably process the [`RepositoryConstraintViolationException`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/core/RepositoryConstraintViolationException.java), I'm not sure if `spring-data-rest` handles them already.