# What is the best way to write a AuthenticationFilter with REST features?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

Below is  what I have so far but it doesn't do what I want. What I want is a 415 if the content type isn't json, and a 400 jackson can't deserialize or if the validation is wrong. Currently of course this is all 401s and I'm doing something wrong with deserialization (was passing the wrong type to json). I'm thinking there may be some way to harness what Spring MVC would do under the hood for a regular controller.

```
@Component
public class JsonAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Validator validator;

    protected JsonAuthenticationFilter( final ObjectMapper objectMapper, final Validator validator ) {
        super( new AntPathRequestMatcher( "/authentication/password", "POST" ) );
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response )
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        if ( request.getContentType() == null
            || !MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.isCompatibleWith( MediaType.parseMediaType( request.getContentType() ) ) ) {
            response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE );
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                "Media Type not supported: " + request.getContentType() );
        }

        PasswordCredentials credentials = objectMapper.readValue( request.getReader(), PasswordCredentials.class );
        DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder( credentials );
        dataBinder.setValidator( validator );
        dataBinder.validate();

        AbstractAuthenticationToken authRequest = credentials.toAuthenticationToken();

        setDetails( request, authRequest );

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate( authRequest );
    }

    /**
     * Provided so that subclasses may configure what is put into the authentication
     * request's details property.
     *
     * @param request     that an authentication request is being created for
     * @param authRequest the authentication request object that should have its details
     *                    set
     */
    protected void setDetails( HttpServletRequest request, AbstractAuthenticationToken authRequest ) {
        authRequest.setDetails( authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails( request ) );
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager( final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager ) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager( authenticationManager );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide PasswordCredentials object and a json message format you are sending?

Comment: Don't write it yourself, look up proven examples. Good source would be JHipster for start (https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-token)

Comment: @jlumietu http://stackoverflow.com/q/39166509/206466 I don't think the structure is particularly relevent, only change is that I changed `toAuthentication` to `toAuthenticaitonToken`

Comment: @Vaelyr proven examples means writing it myself... this code is based off Spring Security's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using JWT authentication, or at least some sort of token-based authentication, right? You're better off using a `@RestController` that delegates authentication to the `authenticationManager` than working with lower-level filter semantics.

Here's a controller I've used previously, a bit modified to comply with your DTO. You'll notice it looks a lot like [the suggested JHipster example](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-token/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/UserJWTController.java):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class LoginController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public LoginController(
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(
      value = "/login", 
      method = RequestMethod.POST, 
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) // will cause 415 errors
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(
        @Valid @RequestBody PasswordCredentials request) { // validated implicitly
        try {
            final User principal = doAuthenticate(request);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(tokenFor(principal));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error authenticating user", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }

    private String tokenFor(final User principal) {
        return tokenAuthenticationService.createTokenForUser(principal);
    }

    private User doAuthenticate(PasswordCredentials request) {
        final Authentication authentication = request.toAuthenticationToken();
        final Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
        return (User) authenticated.getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

To see how Spring controllers resolve, parse and validate JSON request body parameters, you should look at [RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java), specifically its [`resolveArgument`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html#resolveArgument-org.springframework.core.MethodParameter-org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer-org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest-org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebDataBinderFactory-) method and implement something similar in your filter. However, since your filter is not a controller you should adapt the code to suit your needs by remove all references to the `MethodParameter` parameter.

Comment: I'm actually not doing tokens, just authenticating via json, and then letting spring session take over (in which case I'm just doing cookies with SESSION ), and my previous question, shows that I was writing a controller, but I found out it wasn't using spring session after. This has a lot to do with serving static content that needs authentication to view, and having it being easier to just let it get served with a SESSION than wrapping it with "ajax".

Basically I am just processing the login form with json instead of url encoded.

Comment: Well, even in that case I think you're better off with a controller approach, you'd have even less code. But if you still wish on going with filters, I think your own approach is better than trying to use Spring's own components that get applied to controllers - less code and probably a bit better performance, too. I'll update my answer to also include pointers on how to use Spring's way, too.

Comment: I mean, I might be better off with the controller approach but it doesn't set the session appropriately, not sure if it's not doing anything else

Comment: You could invoke the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` from the controller manually but yeah, I get what you mean, Spring Security does a lot of other stuff for you which you may be missing out on without the filter. Then I suggest you stick with your own version of the filter, trying to replicate the controller's support for parsing and validation would just leave you with a needlessly more complicated codebase.